# Regex to match and replace text in yaml file using sed command

Tags: linux, sed

```
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:494e51b1bdf474aa5e6a73d9c0f49d0d471dd44"
    - name: apicurio-registry-jpa
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-jpa-rhel8@sha256:15abbd968d8d2cb4e7b39c8fab9ded2eb67435ca8bf"
    - name: apicurio-registry-infinispan
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-infinispan-rhel8@sha256:42bc4f781d50a415d8d91d389f231907dd0253"
```

I have a requirement where I need to replace the image references very frequently in  the above yaml file. So basically I need to replace the 3 image references present inside the double quotes in line 4,6 and 8 like this:-

**Replace the below image references**:-

```
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:494e51b1bdf474aa5e6a73d9c0f49d0d471dd44
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-jpa-rhel8@sha256:15abbd968d8d2cb4e7b39c8fab9ded2eb67435ca8bf
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-infinispan-rhel8@sha256:42bc4f781d50a415d8d91d389f231907dd0253
```

**with the latest image references**:-

```
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:a57957dad0f9d2ba682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-jpa-rhel8@sha256:6be04e95d9d627f448f02e8557916973282d4b6cb76
registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-infinispan-rhel8@sha256:a682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43a5f508a547o907
```

**And the output file should be**:-

```
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:a57957dad0f9d2ba682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43"
    - name: apicurio-registry-jpa
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-jpa-rhel8@sha256:6be04e95d9d627f448f02e8557916973282d4b6cb76"
    - name: apicurio-registry-infinispan
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-infinispan-rhel8@sha256:a682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43a5f508a547o907"
```

**Could somebody please help me with 3 sed commands to find and replace the image references present within the double quotes as showed above ?**

**Note**: Please note that the alphanumeric values after the **rhel8@sha** is dynamic and is not constant. So, solution like this won't work:-

```
sed -e 's|registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:494e51b1bdf474aa5e6a73d9c0f49d0d471dd44|registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:a57957dad0f9d2ba682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43|'
```

**I am looking for a more dynamic solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on comments to original answer:

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$ cat input.txt
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:a57957dad0f9d2ba682a0e4af25804bfdf77ef43"
$ sed 's|registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-[^"]*|registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:494e51b1bdf474aa5e6a73d9c0f49d0d471dd44|' input.txt
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:494e51b1bdf474aa5e6a73d9c0f49d0d471dd44"
$
```

This time we use a regex to pick up any text that follows *apicurio-registry-streams-*

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add the main point. The alpha-numeric digits afetr 'rhel8@sha:` is dynamic and it wont be the same always. So the above solution is a atatic solution and I am looking for a dynamic one

Comment: Then use variables to generate your sed command dynamically.  eg. `$ pattern=foo/bar
$ replace=bar/baz$ cat input.txt
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "foo/bar"
$ sed -e "s|${pattern}|${replace}|" input.txt
spec:
  relatedImages:
    - name: apicurio-registry-streams
      image: "bar/baz"
$`

Comment: I would only know the replacement string but will not know the string to be matched after `rhel8@sha` @kingsindian

Comment: Are you saying you know you have to replace the value for `apicurio-registry-streams` with some value of `registry.stage.blah-blah` regardless of what the original value was?  ie. the pattern we need to key off is `apicurio-registry-streams` on the previous line?

Comment: What I am saying is in the string "registry.stage.xyz.io/integration/apicurio-registry-streams-rhel8@sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", except the x part, other things remain constant. I just have to replace the xxxxxxxxxxxx part.

Comment: Original answer has been updated to do what you need.